# get first record from different databasename data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have this data in emp table:

```
id  |dbname
1   |db1
2   |db1
1   |db1
2   |db2
3   |db2
5   |db2
1   |db2
4   |db3
1   |db3
3   |db3
```

Emp table has database related records (db1,db2,db3... etc) and if same id exists in different database(db1,db2,db3 etc) then I need to retrieve first dbname. Based on above table data I want output like below

```
Id  |  dbname
1   |  db1
2   |  db1
3   |  db2
5   |  db2
4   |  db3
```

Comment: what do you mean by "first databasename only" is there a date column on which you want to get the data?

Comment: @JamesZ, what do you mean by the *indian way*?

Comment: @wewesthemenace Using only not to describe that you need to fetch only something, but to give focus to the previous word

Comment: I tried to fix the question to be little bit more clear, and removed only since it doesn't make sense there :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this solution:

```sql
create table #empTable (ID INT, DBName varchar(10))

insert into #empTable values (1,'db1'), (2,'db1'), (1,'db1'), (2,'db2'), (3,'db2'), (5,'db2'), (1,'db2'), (4,'db3'), (1,'db3'), (3,'db3')

select a.ID, a.DBName
from
(
    select e.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by ID) as Rnk
    from #empTable e
) a
where a.Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *first database* means alphabetical:

You can use `MIN` function:

```
SELECT 
   Id,
   MIN(dbname) AS dbname
FROM emp
GROUP BY Id
```

Or `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    Id, dbname
FROM(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY dbname)
    FROM emp
)t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Not sure if OP means `MIN` when referring to "first databasename only"

Comment: I just assume it's alphabetical.

Comment: seems to be the case unless there is a date column/identity column (not mentioned in the question) on the basis on which OP wants first value

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below query its given correct result.any one please share any different ways. thanks!

```
;with abc as
  (select * , ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by id order by dbname) as b
  from   [Test].[dbo].[test123])
  select  id,dbname from abc where b=1
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as what I've posted earlier? You can also use `MIN`.

Comment: if this is what you tried. this should be an edit to the question and not an answer. you still didn't answer my question. what is your definition of " first dbname"?